# Prevent command from executing in channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to prevent my bot's commands from running in specific channels - without putting a check at the start of every command the bot has.

I have this on_command event right now:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command(self, ctx):
        aroles=ctx.author.roles
        aroles.reverse()
        blacklist=["role", "role", "role", "role", "role"] # Roles I don't want to include in the roles list.. if that makes sense
        roles=[id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id] # Roles that can run commands anywhere
        channel=get(ctx.guild.channels, id=id) # Commands channel
        
        for role in aroles:
            if role.name not in blacklist:
                if role.id in roles: # If they have one of the roles, do nothing and let the command run
                    return
                elif ctx.channel == channel: # If they are in the commands channel, do nothing and let the command run
                    return
                else:
                    # something??
                    await ctx.send(f"Commands can only be ran in {channel.mention}", delete_after=3)
                    # something??
```

This event works fine except for the fact that the bot doesn't cancel the command from running after, or before, it sends the "use #commands" message and that is because I've no idea how I would do that.

I've tried a few different methods that I can't remember but haven't worked, so I'm hoping someone here knows how I would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:**
I scrapped the whole on_command thing and, with my friend, made a new invoke that works fine.

Comment: Why don't you make a simple [global check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.check)?

Comment: Of course I miss something that could make life easier. Only thing is I still don't know a method of stopping the command from actually running..

Comment: If the global check returns a falsy value the command won't be executed and `commands.CheckFailure` will be raised.

Comment: I haven't used global checks much, sorry if it's a bit annoying, but do you have an example of how that'd work? Or how I could implement what I'm attempting to do into the check?

Comment: Im unsure what you're really trying to do, the code is really messy, also in the title you're stating "Prevent command from executing in channels", the code looks like you're trying to "prevent command from executing by certain roles"

Comment: No, that's not what I'm trying to do at all. Basically I: get the author's roles, reverse the list so it goes from the top down, remove roles that I don't want to be in the list, make a list of roles that can use commands in any channel, check to see if the author has any of those roles (if they do, return and it carries on with the command) then check if the command was run in the commands channel (if it was, return then the command runs) and if someone doesn't have one of the roles in the list or didn't run the commands in the right channel, it's meant to prevent the command from running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_message` method is a bit tricky to implement when you are using cogs and also advanced prefixes or etc...

So I tested overwriting a method that will invoke the commands.

```py
default_invoke = bot.invoke
async def new_invoke(self, ctx: Context):
    if ctx.command:
        if 'something is wrong':
            return

    await self.default_invoke(ctx)
bot.invoke = new_invoke
```

You must return only if the condition you are looking for is false. Otherwise, allow the default invoke trigger.

Also `if ctx.command:` is important since this method will be triggered even if the command is not specified and this check will pass only if the command is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_message` event is called before the command is invoked. So this is the correct method for your problem. If I recall correctly you have to put the `on_message` event in your main Cog in order to work properly. Otherwise, you won't override the `on_message` event of the main Cog which results in the message being processed anyway.
Also, you need to include the `process_commands` at the end of your `on_message` method because otherwise the command is not processed. Without that line all your commands would not work at all (assuming you were able to fix the problem). Assuming you add the line without fixing your problem first all commands which are supposed to run are getting executed twice and all the ones u want to prevent from happening are only executed once. That should also confirm for you that the `on_message`method is working correct.

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialisation stuff here 
        intents = discord.Intents.default()

        super().__init__(command_prefix="-", intents=intents) # all your other stuff here

    def run(self):
        super().run("token")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if your_check_here:
            return 
            # the return prevents the provess_commands from being executed and therefore the command not being executed
        
        # Make sure to include this, because otherwise the message won't be processed
        await self.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: the problem with this method is that you can not access the ctx and maybe the ctx be important for ya